# Quorum & web3j: Transaction has failed with status: 0x0. Gas used: 0. (not-enough gas?)

Tags: web3j, quorum

I'm doing some play & test with Quorum. I'm using example 7nodes with docker. The network is up and my simple smart contract is deployed with a `set` and a `get` function. When I call the `set` function with `Quorum web3j` I get below error:

> Transaction has failed with status: 0x0. Gas used: 0. (not-enough gas?)

Although the `get` function works fine. And also the `set` function works OK in remix ide. Has anyone seen this error before?

Here is the contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract Test {

  uint256 number;

  constructor() public {}

  function set (uint256 n) public {
    number = n;
  }

  function get () public view returns (uint256) {
    return number;
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you sending this transaction?

Comment: did you manage to fix this issue?